# set some property for array type element in node soap

Tags: soap, node-soap

i get xml like this when using node-soap in my app :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:impl="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" 
  xmlns:intf="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" 
  xmlns:tns1="urn:SOAPSmsQueue">
  <soap:Header></soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <impl:enqueue>
      <domain>magfa</domain>
      <messageBodies>
        <messageBodies>hi</messageBodies>
      </messageBodies>
      <recipientNumbers>
        <recipientNumbers>989187004197</recipientNumbers>
      </recipientNumbers>
      <senderNumbers>
        <senderNumbers>98300079368</senderNumbers>
      </senderNumbers>
    </impl:enqueue>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

so i want's to add some property to array elements.
some property like this : `soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"`

and create array element like this :

```
  <messageBodies soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
    <messageBodies>hi</messageBodies>
  </messageBodies>
```

finally i want my xml are look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:impl="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" 
  xmlns:intf="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" 
  xmlns:tns1="urn:SOAPSmsQueue">
  <soap:Header></soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <impl:enqueue>
      <domain>magfa</domain>
      <messageBodies soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
        <messageBodies>hi</messageBodies>
      </messageBodies>
      <recipientNumbers soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
        <recipientNumbers>989381028800</recipientNumbers>
      </recipientNumbers>
      <senderNumbers soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <senderNumbers >98300079368</senderNumbers>
      </senderNumbers>
    </impl:enqueue>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

this description just for silly validation in stackoverflow for this question `is looks like your post is mostly code ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <messageBodies soap-enc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soap-enc:Array" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
    <messageBodies>hi</messageBodies>
  </messageBodies>
```

soap-enc instead of soapenc

Comment: I just want to add `soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"` with nod-soap to array element it's work for me

Comment: Have you fix that problem ?

Comment: It might be better to refer the official scheme specification describing the standard scheme practice here: https://www.w3.org/2000/xp/Group/1/08/29/soap12-part2.html#arrays